# Fetching API data with React

Tags: reactjs, fetch

So I'm trying to fetch data from my API and I'm able to log it into console, but I can't render it into my app using useState. Tried something like that and it completely ignores my h2.

```
var id = "61bf209bdb079818ec63d9fd";

const Main = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [fromApi, setFromApi] = useState([]);
    
    const getApiData = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/myapi')
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                setFromApi(data);
            })
        
        for (var i = 0; i < fromApi.length; i++) {
            if (fromApi[i]._id === id) {
                setName(fromApi[i].name);
            }
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getApiData();
    }, [])
    
    return (
        <div>
            {name && <h2 className='urname'>Your name: {name}</h2>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Your `for` loop should be called inside the `then()` after the `fetch`. Currently you run the `for loop` before the data has loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because **React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately**. This makes reading state right after updating (in your case setFromApi) a potential pitfall and can potentially return the existing value due to async nature.

- Calling `setState` [only affects the next render](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/state-as-a-snapshot) and does not change state in the already running code

React Doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?#setstate

In your case you're using data receiving from API and running `for` loop even before `fromAPI` state gets updated. Instead put `fromAPI` in dependency array to `useEffect` and perform your `for` loop there.

```
var id = "61bf209bdb079818ec63d9fd";

const Main = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [fromApi, setFromApi] = useState([]);
    
    const getApiData = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/myapi')
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                setFromApi(data);
            })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getApiData();
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
      if(fromApi?.length){
        for (var i = 0; i < fromApi.length; i++) {
            if (fromApi[i]._id === id) {
                setName(fromApi[i].name);
            }
        }
      }
    }, [fromApi])
    
    return (
        <div>
            {name && <h2 className='urname'>Your name: {name}</h2>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider why you have two states of `fromApi` and `name`?  You could just `setName` as soon as the data comes back from the API...something like:

```
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    
    const getApiData = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/myapi')
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    if (data[i]._id === id) {
                        setName(data[i].name);
                        // Stop the for loop once match has been found
                        return;
                    }
                }
            })
    }
```